# Reference Frames and the De Broglie Wavelength

Tags: quantum-mechanics, reference-frames, wavelength

If the de Broglie wavelength of a massive particle, is h/mv then doesn't that mean interference patterns and everything change their properties depending on the velocity of the observer?

How can QM be provide consistent predictions in different reference frames with different observers expecting different wavelengths?

Comment: Why not try some example case for yourself; e.g. analyse Young's slits experiment in two different frames. Also, you could work out the answer to the same question for classical light waves.

Comment: Would it be a case of using doppler shift to figure out the wavelength the wall sees?

Comment: Still pretty new at this.

Comment: Thanks for that btw, something about the classical light waves  really helped reframe the problem.

Comment: Do you understand about complex wavefunctions like $e^{i(kx-\omega t)}$? This isn't going to come out right if you try to use real-valued wavefunctions.

Comment: @AndrewSteane: The classical E&M version is pretty different from the version the OP is discussing, which is nonrelativistic quantum mechanics. The observables are different, because in one case the amplitude is observable and in the other case only the squared amplitude. Also, the transformation properties are totally different.

Comment: @BenCrowell On the contrary, the fact that an almost identical question can be asked about classical wave optics shows that this issue is not essentially about QM but about wave phenomena more generally. Furthermore, the fact that the two cases have different transformation properties is itself very informative. What you identify as bugs are here features.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a proof that any measurements of the position of any particle are independent of the observer's velocity.

Consider a particle in a state described in the momentum basis,
$$
|\Psi\rangle=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\tilde\Psi(p)|p\rangle dp.
$$
The position wave function can be found from the Fourier transform, so if,
$$
|\Psi\rangle=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\Psi(x)|x\rangle dx,
$$
$$
\Psi(x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi\hbar}}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\tilde\Psi(p)e^{i\frac{px}{\hbar}}dp.
$$
Let the momentum of the particle observed from a moving reference frame be $p'=p+mv$. Then, if the moving observer observes a state $|p'\rangle$, the stationary observer observes a state $|p\rangle$, so the wavefunction from the moving reference frame is $\tilde\Psi'(p')=\tilde\Psi(p)$.
So, the particle from the perspective of the moving reference frame is in the state,
$$
|\Psi'\rangle=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\tilde\Psi'(p')|p'\rangle dp'=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\tilde\Psi(p)|p'\rangle dp'.
$$
So now we can calculate the position wave function from the moving reference frame,
$$
\Psi'(x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi\hbar}}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\tilde\Psi(p)e^{i\frac{p'x}{\hbar}}dp'.
$$
Performing a change of variable, since dp=dp',
$$
\Psi'(x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi\hbar}}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\tilde\Psi(p)e^{i\frac{(p+mv)x}{\hbar}}dp=e^{i\frac{mvx}{\hbar}}\Psi(x).
$$
So, when we calculate the probability density of the particle being at position x, we get the same no matter which reference frame we choose,
$$
\text{Pr}_x=\left|\Psi'(x)\right|^2=\left|e^{i\frac{mvx}{\hbar}}\Psi(x)\right|^2=\left|\Psi(x)\right|^2.
$$
Therefore, although the particle has a different wavefunction in each reference frame, both observers agree on what would actually happen if you where to measure the position of the particle.

Answer (score 1):

This turns out to be a classic example of why we need to use complex numbers for the values of wavefunctions.

There are three basic facts that we have to start with:

1. The wavefunction $\Psi$ is not observable. Only $|\Psi|^2$ is.
2. The wavelength changes according to the rule $k\rightarrow k+(m/\hbar)v$, where the wave number $k$ is $2\pi/\lambda$. (This is just the de Broglie relation plus Galilean addition of velocities, notated in terms of $k$ rather than $\lambda$ for convenience.)
3. Distances between observable points are invariant, because this is nonrelativistic quantum mechanics. (There is no length contraction.)

This doesn't work with real wavefunctions. If you have an oscillating real wavefunction, then it crosses zero at certain points. Zero squared gives zero probability density, so the locations of these zeroes is observable. The distances between these observable points is invariant, but this gives a contradiction with 2, because it makes the wavelength invariant.

So we actually have to do this using complex-valued wavefunctions. To keep the observable probabilities invariant, we have to have a transformation law for $\Psi$ that only changes its phase. We do this using the transformation law $\Psi\rightarrow e^{-ikx}\Psi$, which behaves as in 2.

In the example of double-slit interference, the fringes all stay the same, because the probabilities are invariant.